# Draw a rectangle inside margins

Tags: tikz-pgf, margins

I am new to LaTeX and I am trying to place a rectangle (filled in red for instance) at the very top of all the pages of my document. The rectangle should be 0.5 cm high and with the page width.

I saw a lot of complicated threads to do that, but cannot manage to reproduce it.

My basic attempt by drawing a rectangle with \tikzpicture:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill[red] (0,0) rectangle (\paperwidth, 0.5cm)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The problem is that LaTeX only starts drawing at the top left corner of the margin and not of the page.
I tried to use \voffset but nothing changes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Welcome to TeX SX! You don't really need `TikZ` for that: a simple coloured `\rule` will do, and the `eso-pic` package will let you insert what you want at any position in the page:

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{svgnames}{xcolor}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[texcoord]{eso-pic}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\AddToShipoutPictureBG{\AtPageUpperLeft{\color{Tomato}\rule[-5mm]{\paperwidth}{5mm}}}

\begin{document}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Bernard, it works great ! Plus, I discovered new options. Note: I had to remove the option "showframe" in the geometry package. It crashed otherwise (maybe my distro does not support it).

Comment: It's not your distribution, but probably you real code (or your real class) already loads geometry without this option, which is usually loaded for verification purpose, but isn't used in production.